# SWIFTUI: NavigationStack breaks what NavigationView was doing correctly. What's the best solution?

Tags: swift, swiftui-navigationview

In one of the projects I decided to comply with apple and get rid of NavigationView.
In the project you had a list of buildings and after choosing a Building you had several tabs with bills, documents etc. Each of the Tabs was a different view, each with its own toolbar, buttons and functions. Here's the sample code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct TestView: View {
    
    var testData: [Building] = [
        Building(name: "Crystal Balls"),
        Building(name: "Geneva Towers"),
        Building(name: "Villa Navagero"),
    ]
    
    
    var body: some View {

//Here's the problem... If I change it to NavigationStack 
//all the of toolbars in tabs are gone

        NavigationView {
            List(testData) {test in
                NavigationLink {
                    TabView {
                        NavigationStack{
                            Text(test.name)
                                .navigationTitle("My Bills")
                                .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
                                .toolbar{
                                    ToolbarItem{
                                        Button{} label: {
                                            Image(systemName: "gear.circle")
                                        }
                                    }
                                    ToolbarItem{
                                        Button{} label: {
                                            Image(systemName: "plus.circle")
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                        }
                                .tabItem{
                                    Label("Bills", systemImage: "doc.fill.badge.ellipsis")
                                }
                            
                            Text(test.name)
                                .tabItem{
                                    Label("Skills", systemImage: "doc.fill")
                                }
                            
                        
                    }
                    
                    
                } label: {
                    Text(test.name)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct TestView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TestView()
    }
}
```

Having every tab as a different view and having a back button is too convenient, getting all the toolbar button to the TabView seems to "dirty" and inefficient.
Maybe somebody has figured out a solution?

Comment: `TabView` should always be at the very top, each tab can have their own `NavigationView`/`NavigationStack`, I am sure there are a ton of little bugs you have been fighting with his setup. Apple specifies this setup in the Human Interface Guidelines.

Comment: Yes, I understand, but logic-wise it is not right. I have a lot of buildings and each building has 3-4 tabs with information, not wise-versa. So how can I start with tabs if the building is not yet chosen, that's why I went with this design

Comment: You have to create custom solutions, this design is not compatible with the standard views